# Make repository invisible in domain layer of Clean Architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I recently heard and researched about Clean Architecture and am trying to implement it on my own to understand it deeply, I know **Domain** module(layer) has the logic and should have some interfaces as well as UseCases which use the repositories. As far as I learned, the **Domain** layer does not have access to any other layers but **Data** and **Presentation** layer has access to the **Domain** layer but not to each other.

My repositories definition (Interfaces) are in the **Domain** module and their implementation is in **Data** module and then injected by Dagger. Also, I have some **UseCases** which inject some repositories.

The problem that I have is, the **Presentation** module has access to the repositories interfaces and use-cases as both are in the **Domain** module and are imported with gradle in the **Presentation** layer.

I do not think having access to both in the **Presentation** module would be good, I am using Kotlin and **internal** keyword to isolate classes for each module but as **Data** module needs to have access to repositories interfaces to implement them, I cannot use **internal** keyword for them so they are exposed now.

My question is, would it be possible to change the design somehow to expose only the use-cases?

Comment: Is it really a problem that interfaces are accessible to the presentation layer? of course u could put the interfaces in separate module and make only use cases and data depend on it but is it really worth the added complexity?

Comment: Not really, but it is against of Clean Architecture principle and makes developers confuse about which one should be used? UseCase or Repositories?

Answer (score 2):

If `UseCase` is related to data (e.g. `ReadUserUseCase`), then it's interface should stay in the `domain` module and the implementation should be moved to the `data` module.

Comment: Yes, but as I read everywhere, you need to have their interfaces (not implementation) in the domain layer. In other words, if I put my repositories interfaces into the data layer as the domain layer should have any dependencies to data layer or presentation, then I cannot have access to my repositories in UseCases classes.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread the question and thought that your `domain` module depends on `data`. Now I see it is the other way so I'm editing my answer.

Comment: But as I understood from Clean Architecture, business logic should be in Domain module, does not your approach violate the clean architecture principals?